# SoapHeader and problems with non-unicode characters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, utf-8, soaphandler

I created

```
public class ExceptionHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
```

I want to create soap header with non-ascii characters.

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMsg = factory.createMessage();
//soapMsg.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "utf-8");
SOAPHeaderElement aaa = soapMsg.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName("test", "aaa"));
aaa.addTextNode("ść");
context.setMessage(soapMsg);
```

What i get in response is:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header>
       <aaa xmlns="test">Ĺ›Ä‡</aaa>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body/>
</env:Envelope>
```

Does this api do not support nonascii characters or is it a bug?

Comment: It’s not a bug.  Either you are viewing the XML in an editor that thinks the XML is in a one-byte encoding (like windows-125x) instead of UTF-8, or the Java compiler assumed your source file was using a one-byte encoding when in fact it was using UTF-8.

Comment: yes it was a matter of project.build.sourceEncoding in maven project (default encoding of maven-compiler-plugin)